# admob bannerAd shows Ad after about a minute during gameplay scene ignores bannerAd.isHidden xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob

my game has two bannerAd types a top banner and bottom banner the top only shows during gameplay scene and the bottom only shows in mainmenu it works except for some reason after about a minute during gameplay my top banner hides and my bottom shows this is my code for

`

```
    var bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape)
    var bannerViewPortrait = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            initializeAds()
            initializePortraitAds()

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showBanner), name: Notification.Name("showBanner"), object: nil)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(hideBanner), name: Notification.Name("hideBanner"), object: nil)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showPortraitBanner), name: Notification.Name("showPortraitBanner"), object: nil)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(hidePortraitBanner), name: Notification.Name("hidePortraitBanner"), object: nil)



            if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
                    if let scene = MainMenuScene(fileNamed: "MainMenu") {
                            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                            view.presentScene(scene)
                    }

                    view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

                    view.showsFPS = true
                    view.showsNodeCount = true
                    view.showsPhysics = false
            }
    }

    func showBanner() {
            bannerView.isHidden = false
    }
    func showPortraitBanner() {
            bannerViewPortrait.isHidden = false
    }
    func hidePortraitBanner() {
            bannerViewPortrait.isHidden = true
    }
    func hideBanner() {
            bannerView.isHidden = true
    }

    func initializeAds() {
            bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(bannerView)
            bannerView.isHidden = true

            bannerView.delegate = self

            bannerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
            bannerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            bannerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

            bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
            bannerView.rootViewController = self
            bannerView.load(GADRequest())
    }
    func initializePortraitAds() {
            bannerViewPortrait.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(bannerViewPortrait)
            bannerViewPortrait.isHidden = true

            bannerViewPortrait.delegate = self

            bannerViewPortrait.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            bannerViewPortrait.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            bannerViewPortrait.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

            bannerViewPortrait.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
            bannerViewPortrait.rootViewController = self
            bannerViewPortrait.load(GADRequest())

    }

    func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
            hideBanner()
            showPortraitBanner()
    }

    func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
            hideBanner()
            hidePortraitBanner()
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }`
```

and my gameplayscene
`

```
 override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("showBanner"), object: nil)
  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("hidePortraitBanner"), object: nil)}

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("showBanner"), object: nil)
  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("hidePortraitBanner"), object: nil)}`
```

please excuse my messy code I just starting learning

@Jake T. you are absolutely right there is no need for two bannerViews here is my attempt with only one variable as you can see from my code I am very much a beginner

`

```
   var bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    initializeAds()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(topBanner), name: Notification.Name("topBanner"), object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(bottomBanner), name: Notification.Name("bottomBanner"), object: nil)



    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            if let scene = MainMenuScene(fileNamed: "MainMenu") {
                    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                    view.presentScene(scene)
            }

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
            view.showsPhysics = false
    }
    }

    func topBanner() {
    bannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape
    bannerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    bannerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    bannerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true


    }

    func bottomBanner() {
    bannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait
    bannerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    bannerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    bannerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

    }

    func initializeAds() {
    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(bannerView)
    bannerView.isHidden = true

    bannerView.delegate = self

    bannerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    bannerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    bannerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
    }


    func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    bannerView.isHidden = false

    }

    func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {

    bannerView.isHidden = true
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

`func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
            hideBanner()
            showPortraitBanner()
    }`

This hides the top banner, and shows the bottom banner. Edit: I can't be 100% sure this is the source of your error, because you don't show anywhere how this method is getting called, but it's most likely your error. You probably just want to swap `showPortraitBanner()` with `hidePortraitBanner()`

Also, your banners have weird names. You should change the name to "topBanner" and "bottomBanner" or something. Portrait vs landscape is like, holding your phone vertically or horizontally. Which means, you're kinda using the wrong banners for at least one of these, unless you are, in fact, only showing these while in the proper orientation. If your game is only in a single orientation, you should change one of those very first two lines you put here so that they're both the proper orientation.

Comment: I did hideBanner() because otherwise it would show the bottom and top banner on my mainMenuScene and if I do hidePortraitBanner() the portrait banner won't show unless I go in options and come back to mainmenu the names are weird I know but the reason I did that is because I want a skinny or smartLandscape to show on my gameplay scene and a normal smartPortrait on my mainMenuScene

Comment: Comment out that showPortraitBanner() call and I bet neither banner will be displayed. If not, you don't have enough code to receive help. 

My guess here is that that is a method that will be getting called when *either* banner receives an ad, which means that any time your banners fetch an ad, the top one will hide and the bottom one will show. You should probably check to see if the top view controller is your menu or your game, and call the appropriate show function based on that.

Comment: You made `self` the delegate for both of these banners, so they share delegate methods. You need to either differentiate the handling within the delegate methods, or declare separate delegates. 

And, a better idea in general here, would just be to use a single banner view, so you can just always display the same one. Instantiate it appropriately as you switch to the menu / game.

Comment: I updated the code with your suggestion of using one bannerView but I am totally clueless as to how it should be properly implemented

Comment: Right now you aren't calling top / bottom banner, unless that notification is getting triggered somewhere else. I would add to your `viewWillAppear:` (or the equivalent for scenes, I've only worked with VCs) for both your menu and your game, the appropriate notification for top/bottomBanner. If these scenes work like VCs, viewWillAppear gets called whenever that VC is going to be displayed on the top. So, if you're pushing it, or if you're popping the one on top of it. This will put your banner ad in the appropriate place. The next step is figuring out how / when to trigger an ad and doing so.